# Does 'fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF' will affect on source code?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I faced `fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF` and also resolved using

`git config --global core.safecrlf false`

I also read so many detail about it on internet and Stackoverflow also.I want to know that does ignoring and resolving this affect the compilation of source code in cross platform projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eol, LF or CRLF, does no change the  compiling result. But for some editors on linux, a '^M' will be shown at the end of line when use CRLF format.